# How to pass paramters from one page to another in Dotvvm

Tags: dotvvm

How do I pass more than one parameter on a URL from one page to another page.  For example: from page1, I use a link to pass parameters to page 2.
Also in Page2 how do I get the parameters off the query string?

From Page 1 Link to:
/customers/page2.dothtml?Id=5&Date=3/31/2016

How is this link to be coded in DOTVVM?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is from Tomas Herceg at Dotvvm:

There are two things about the URL:

1) DotVVM uses routing for all pages, it is not possible to access the page using the path to the dothtml file. 
You need to register a route in the DotvvmStartupcs file (https://www.dotvvm.com/docs/tutorials/basics-routing/latest), or alternatively you can auto-discover routes.

2) Then, the page should be matched by the routing mechanism. If it's not, I would suspect the / characters in the query parameter - they should be URL-encoded.

3) If you want to make hyperlinks from one page to another, I would recommend using the  and composes the URL for you.
https://www.dotvvm.com/docs/controls/builtin/RouteLink/latest